# Which server is used in script?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

In MS SQL Server, if I'm connected to two servers (for example dev and production) that both have a DB called MyDb which server is targeted when I run a  script like

```
use MyDb

SELECT Description
FROM MyDescriptions
WHERE Description LIKE '%something%'
```

I'm using SSMS. I'm not asking about how to get the information but rather what the consequence will be.

Comment: What do you mean, "what the consequence will be"? If you think you're on dev but you're on production, you'll get data from production. There are easy ways to make it obvious that SSMS is connected to production (start with [custom colors in registered servers](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3565/assign-colors-in-sql-server-management-studio-query-windows-based-on-environment/)).

Comment: I think i just undestood that each file in SSMS is connected to a server and the code i execute in it will use that server. So to know which one ill check which file/window im writing in.

Comment: You can see which server you are connected to by putting your mouse over the tab at the top of the query window in SSMS, or you can also see in the properties window under "Server name".

Comment: The status bar will tell you too. But you have to lose this association between a file and a server. A file has no idea what server it is (or was) connected to; SSMS tells it what server to connect to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each tab in SSMS is either linked to a SQL Server instance or working offline (disconnected). Whenever you open a `.sql` file in SSMS, it will automatically try to connect to the selected Instance and Database on your Object Explorer. When executing a query while offline it will pop up the connection window.

You can see the current connected instance if you hover the mouse over a connected tab or in the status bar at the bottom (default), next to the username and SPID, if you didn't hide it.

Scripts can't store the initial instance's connection. So make sure to connect previously to the proper instance. You might use `sqlcmd` inside scripts to connect to different instances but I don't think that's your concern.

There are add-ins like [SSMS Tools](https://www.ssmstoolspack.com/) in which you can [map instances to color bars](https://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features?f=2) that are displayed on the side, up or down so for example you can map your Dev instance to color red and your Prod environment to green.